# Rudin real and complex analysis Exercise 15.7

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose $f$ is an entire function, $f(\sqrt{n}) = 0$ for $n =1,2,3,\ldots$, and there is a positive constant $\alpha$ such that $|f(z)|<\exp(|z|^\alpha)$ for all large enough $|z|$. For which $\alpha$ does it follow that $f(z) = 0$ for all $z$? [Consider $\sin(\pi z^2)$.]

Since $f$ is entire, using a Weierstrass product, the primary model of $f$ is
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-{z\over\sqrt{n}}\right)$$
Since $\sum \left({1\over\sqrt{n}}\right)^3<\infty$ and $\sum \left({1\over\sqrt{n}}\right)^2 = \infty$, we conclude that $f$ is of the form
$$e^{g(z)}\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-{z\over\sqrt{n}}\right)\exp\left({z\over\sqrt{n}}+{z^2\over 2n}\right).$$
for some entire function $g$.

Since the problem is asking to consider $\sin(\pi z^2)$, we consider the order of growth of it.
$$|\sin(\pi z^2)| = \left|{e^{i\pi z^2}-e^{-i\pi z^2}\over 2i}\right|\leq e^{i\pi z^2} = e^{\pi |z|^2}.$$
So, it has the order of growth at most $2$. If we let $z = x-ix$ for $x\in\Bbb R$,
\begin{align*}
\left|{e^{i\pi z^2}-e^{-i\pi z^2}\over 2i}\right|&\geq {1\over 2}\left(|e^{i\pi z^2}|-|e^{-i\pi z^2}|\right)\\
& = {1\over 2}\left(e^{\operatorname{Re}(i\pi z^2)} - e^{\operatorname{Re}(-i\pi z^2)}\right)\\
& = {1\over 2}\left(e^{2\pi x^2}-e^{-2\pi x^2}\right)\\
&\geq C\cdot e^{2\pi x^2}.\\
\end{align*}
for some constant $C$. Hence the order of growth of $\sin(\pi z^2)$ is $2$.

So $2$ may be a candidate of $\alpha$ but I don't know what to do next. Could you help?

Comment: $\alpha=2-\epsilon$ (for $2$ you have an example that works); Jensen theorem is your friend here as it connects the number of zeroes less than $R$ in absolute value with $\log |f|$ on the circle $|z|=R$

Comment: @Conrad We need to show Jensen's formula fails right? Since $f$ is identically zero, then the set of zeros contains a limit point. I edit the post to show my work but wonder if this is a correct way.

Comment: Yes, if $f$ not zero Jensen gives a contradiction - you are definitely on the right path so deduce a contradiction when $n$ goes to infinity

Comment: @Conrad Thank you. I posted my answer.

Comment: @Conrad The function $\sin(\pi z^2)$ doesn't work for $\alpha=2$ since we dont have $\lvert f(z)\rvert <\exp(\lvert z\rvert^2)$ but only  $\lvert f(z)\rvert <\exp(\pi \lvert z\rvert^2)$. Is there some easy way to fix this?

Comment: @Kasper I guess than $\alpha=2$ is allowed since it's part of the theory that if you want $|g(z)| \le e^{a|z|}, 0 \le a < \pi, g(n)=0, n$ integral (natural number is enough) then $g=0$, while all the functions for which $g(n)=0, n$ integer are $h(z)\sin \pi z, h$ entire, so applying this to $f(z^2)$...

Comment: @Conrad Thanks. I had already seen the theorem you mention (Carlsons theorem) but I cant see how to use it: Let $f$ be a function as in the exercise (ie $f(\sqrt{n})=0$ for all natural numbers and $\lvert f(z)\rvert \leq e^{\lvert z\rvert^2}$ for $\lvert z\rvert>>0$), then $g(z)=f(z^2)$ has order $4$, not $1$… What we want is ”$g(z)=f(\sqrt{z})$”, but this isnt allowed……

Comment: @Kasper you use $h(z)=\frac{f(z)}{\sin \pi z^2}$ entire and then $h(z)=O(e^{r^{2+\epsilon})})$ in the angle $|\arg z| <\pi/(4+4\epsilon)$ say while on the boundary where $z^2$ is close to $\pm it, t \in \mathbb R$ we have that $h \to 0, |z| \to \infty$ so $h$ is bounded there; if you rotate a little up and down you get that $h$ is actually bounded in $|\arg z| \le \pi/4$ and then similar proof in the other quadrants with boundaries close to $\pm 3\pi/4, \pm \pi/4$ gives you $h$ bounded in the plane etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Conrad's hint, suppose $\alpha =2-\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$. Suppose $f(\sqrt{n}) =0$ for $n\in\Bbb N$ and $|f(z)|\leq\exp(|z|^{2-\epsilon})$. Suppose $f$ is nonconstant entire. Replacing $f(z)/z^m$ for some $m$ if necessary, we may assume $f(0)\neq 0$. Then by Jensen's formula, we get
$$\log|f(0)|+\sum_{|a_n|<R}\log{R\over |a_n|} = {1\over 2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\log|f(Re^{i\theta})|\ d\theta\leq R^{2-\epsilon},$$
where $a_n$ are roots of $f$. Since $\sqrt{n}$ is a root of $f$ for each $n$,
\begin{align*}
R^{2-\epsilon}& \geq\sum_{\sqrt{n}<R}\log{R\over\sqrt{n}}\\
& \geq\sum_{n<R^2}\log{R\over\sqrt{R}}\\
& = \sum_{n<R^2}{1\over 2}\log R\\
& = O(R^2\log R).\\
\end{align*}
And this is a contradiction for large $R$ which is allowed as $f$ is entire. Hence, $\alpha =2$.

Comment: pretty much correct except at the last line where it should be $>>$ as $O$ in general means $<<$ and something that is $O(R^2\log R)$ can be much smaller of course

Comment: @Conrad Corrected it. For large $R$, inequality fails and this is allowed as $f$ is entire.